# simple php class that counts twitter followers?

Tags: php, oop, twitter, count

I am working on my first php class for wordpress in which I query the twitter api for the current count of followers. I plan to extend this to other social media sites as well once I iron out all the bugs.

The issue is that I am new to OOP and wordpress widget development and am not receiving the intended response.

i have gotten it to work without the caching its just that part i think that is throughing it off maybe.

```
class razor_SocialCount {
    function __construct($user, $api) {
           echo $this->razor_social_count_api($user, $api);
    }

    private function razor_social_count_api($user, $api) {
        if (empty($user) || empty($api)) return false;

        if(false === ($count = get_transient($api.'_recent_count') ) ) {

            switch($api) {
                case ('twitter'):
                    $count = $this->fetch_twitter_count($user);
                break;

                default:
                    $count = 'Function not found.';
                break;
            }

            set_transient($api.'_recent_count', $count, (60 * 60 * 3));
        }

        return number_format(doubleval($count));
    }

    private function fetch_twitter_count($user) {
        $json = wp_remote_get("http://api.twitter.com/1/users/show.json?screen_name=$user");

        if(is_wp_error($json)) return 0;

        $count = json_decode($json['body'], true);

        return intval($count['followers_count']);
    }
}
```

ok so based on some responses and help i recieved i made some slight changes to the class as well as expanded it to include rss subscibers and facebook likes

but still getting weird responses. twitter responseis 0 and others is Function Not Found. when i comment out those error checks i still get the same response.

```
class razor_SocialCount {
private $user;
private $api;
public $count;

function __construct($user, $api) {
    $this->user = $user;
    $this->api = $api;
    return $this->razor_social_count_api();
}

private function razor_social_count_api() {
    if (empty($this->user) || empty($this->api)) return false;

    switch($this->api) {
        case ('facebook'):
            if(false === ($this->count = get_transient('facebook_recent_count'))) {
                $this->count = $this->fetch_facebook_count();
                set_transient('facebook_recent_count', $this->count, (60*60*3));
            }
        break;

        case ('twitter'):
            if(false === ($this->count = get_transient('twitter_recent_count'))) {
                $this->count = $this->fetch_twitter_count();
                set_transient('twitter_recent_count', $this->count, (60*60*3));
            }
        break;

        case ('rss'):
            if(false === ($this->count = get_transient('rss_recent_count'))) {
                $this->count = $this->fetch_rss_count();
                set_transient('rss_recent_count', $this->count, (60*60*3));
            }
        break;

        default:
            $this->count = 'Function not found.';
        break;
    }
}

private function fetch_facebook_count() {
    $json = wp_remote_get("http://graph.facebook.com/$this->user");
    if(is_wp_error($json)) return 0;

    $json = json_decode($json['body'], true);

    return number_format(intval($json['likes']));
}

private function fetch_twitter_count() {
    $json = wp_remote_get("http://api.twitter.com/1/users/show.json?screen_name=$this->user");
    //if(is_wp_error($json)) return 0;

    $json = json_decode($json['body'], true);

    return number_format(intval($json['followers_count']));
}

private function fetch_rss_count() {
    $xml = wp_remote_get("http://feedburner.google.com/api/awareness/1.0/GetFeedData?uri=$this->user");
    //if(is_wp_error($xml)) return 0;

    $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xml['body']);
    return number_format(intval($xml->feed->entry['circulation']));
}

}
```

i am calling it as so

```
$facebook = new razor_SocialCount('midaymcom','facebook');
$twitter = new razor_SocialCount('midaym','twitter');
$feed = new razor_SocialCount('midaym','rss');

echo $facebook->count;
echo $twitter->count;
echo $feed->count;
```

interestingly enough when i comment out the transients it works.

Comment: What response _are_ you receiving?

Comment: Have you tried debugging your code?

Comment: And what is the *intended* response. For instance, how you are instantiating this class, and how are you using it?

Comment: @ matt what do you mean debugging its php i recieve no errors or waringings with eror all enabled if thats what you mean.

Comment: @ halfer im getting the returned 0 like their is an error with the api.  if(is_wp_error($json)) return 0;

Comment: @ jhonathan, I apologize as I am rather new to OOP but by instantiate I take it you mean create a new version of it. I create a new version where I need it in my theme <p><?php new razor_SocialCount('account','twitter'); ?></p> like so

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why your accessing the array with: `$json['body']` remove that and I think your good to go.

Heres a quick example that displays the followers_count

```
<?php
function fetch_twitter_count($user) {
    $json = file_get_contents("http://api.twitter.com/1/users/show.json?screen_name=$user");

    if(is_wp_error($json)) return 0;

    $count = json_decode($json, true);

    return intval($count['followers_count']);
}


echo  number_format(fetch_twitter_count('jhon')); //1,155 
?>
```

**EDIT:**
As you can see from the output below there is NO [body] key:

```
Array
(
    [id] => 6405412
    [id_str] => 6405412
    [name] => Jhon van der Ceelen
    [screen_name] => Jhon
    [location] => Amsterdam - The Netherlands
    [description] => GTD-er, Digital marketeer for over 17 years. Working @MindshareNL - Business Planning Director Digital and Client Leader Digital Unilever and KPN
    [url] => http://www.mindshare.nl
    [protected] => 
    [followers_count] => 1156
    [friends_count] => 471
    [listed_count] => 13
    [created_at] => Tue May 29 07:00:11 +0000 2007
    [favourites_count] => 29
    [utc_offset] => 3600
    [time_zone] => Amsterdam
    [geo_enabled] => 
    [verified] => 
    [statuses_count] => 921
    [lang] => nl
    [status] => Array
        (
            [created_at] => Sat Apr 21 09:05:36 +0000 2012
            [id] => 1.9362652702652E+17
            [id_str] => 193626527026524160
            [text] => Mobile Marketing Nederland | Blog: Mobile Advertising groeit (nu echt) http://t.co/ugjwisnO
            [source] => LinkedIn
            [truncated] => 
            [in_reply_to_status_id] => 
            [in_reply_to_status_id_str] => 
            [in_reply_to_user_id] => 
            [in_reply_to_user_id_str] => 
            [in_reply_to_screen_name] => 
            [geo] => 
            [coordinates] => 
            [place] => 
            [contributors] => 
            [retweet_count] => 0
            [favorited] => 
            [retweeted] => 
            [possibly_sensitive] => 
        )

    [contributors_enabled] => 
    [is_translator] => 
    [profile_background_color] => 9AE4E8
    [profile_background_image_url] => http://a0.twimg.com/profile_background_images/19025441/Binary_TV_Photo_psd.jpg
    [profile_background_image_url_https] => https://si0.twimg.com/profile_background_images/19025441/Binary_TV_Photo_psd.jpg
    [profile_background_tile] => 1
    [profile_image_url] => http://a0.twimg.com/profile_images/24825272/Jhon_normal.jpg
    [profile_image_url_https] => https://si0.twimg.com/profile_images/24825272/Jhon_normal.jpg
    [profile_link_color] => 0000FF
    [profile_sidebar_border_color] => 87BC44
    [profile_sidebar_fill_color] => E0FF92
    [profile_text_color] => 000000
    [profile_use_background_image] => 1
    [show_all_inline_media] => 1
    [default_profile] => 
    [default_profile_image] => 
    [following] => 
    [follow_request_sent] => 
    [notifications] => 
)
```

Im not saying dont use the `is_wp_error($json)` function, I commented it out so I could work with the function.

You need to also check that `wp_remote_get` is actually working as `fetch_twitter_count` will always return at least 0

Edit 2:
Also I see your just echoing your result from the constructor you should return instead and call it like:

`<?php $twitter_folowers = new razor_SocialCount('account','twitter'); ?>`

Then you can echo `$twitter_folowers->count` where ever you want it, else trying to echo it you may have trouble if you need it between html.

Edit 4 - Some changes to the class to make it more oop and not just some encapsulated functions:

```
<?php 
class razor_SocialCount {
    private $user;
    private $api;
    public $count;

    function __construct($user, $api) {
        $this->user = $user;
        $this->api = $api;
        return $this->razor_social_count_api();
    }

    private function razor_social_count_api() {
        if (empty($this->user) || empty($this->api)) return false;

        if(false === ($this->count = get_transient($this->api.'_recent_count'))) {

            switch($this->api) {
                case ('twitter'):
                    $this->count = $this->fetch_twitter_count();
                    break;

                default:
                    $this->count = 'Function not found.';
                    break;
            }

            set_transient($this->api.'_recent_count', $this->count, (60 * 60 * 3));
        }
    }

    private function fetch_twitter_count() {
        $json = file_get_contents("http://api.twitter.com/1/users/show.json?screen_name=$this->user");
        if(is_wp_error($json)) return 0;

        $json = json_decode($json, true);
        return number_format(intval($json['followers_count']));
    }
}

$twitter_count = new razor_SocialCount('jhon','twitter');

echo $twitter_count->count; //1,156
?>
```

Comment: @ Lawrence Cherone
The fetch funstion works fine as a stand alone function. that is why i am puzled as to twhere the issue is. I am recieving the 0 from the error check inside the class. The reson behind the body is to limit the amount of data im working with as In do not need the entire json response. acctualy im not really sure how you are able to pull out the followers count as a top level attribute of the array as without body it would be $count['body']['followers_count'] would it not.

Comment: Also the error check is essential because if i do not recieve the correct response from the api It will fail and provide an erorr to my users which i do not want, it also allows for offline editing of the theme without errors.

Comment: ok hmm good to know i was not aware that phps decode of json did not maintain the same heiarchy of the json feed. as for the function it self i will have to play around with the wp_remote_get to see if that is even working properly. again still not sure as to why it would not work inside the private method. thks

Comment: that could be the problem, that wp_remote_get does not have scope within the class, perhaps use curl or file_get_contents, pretty sure wp_remote_get does nothing special or unique that FGC or curl cant do, also it will help you port your code to other CMS in the future.

Comment: ok so finally got some time to test out your suggestions reason for the ['body'] call is that i get an error without it saying that decode only accepts array. also the issue i am having i believe stems from the transient as if i comment those lines out it works but have no caching.

Comment: ok so added in functionality for facebook and rss subscribers to see if error is coming from somewhere else. again these both work as functions individually outside of class. but know the switch statement is always returning the default of 'Function Not Found' for those options. i updated the code to reflect current state